# Open-source A/B testing (browser-based, multi-variable, Google Analytics-compatible)

Tags: gratis, open-source, javascript, analytics, marketing

I want to perform [A/B testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) on my website.

Requirements:

- Free and Open Source
- No server-side code changes needed
- Multi-variable (for instance A/B C/D, leading to AC AD BC BD)
- Invisible in most URLs (it is OK if the variables appear in form submission URLs, but not on information pages that a user might want to share on social networks)
- Results can be seen on Google Analytics

Comment: Allegedly, https://facebook.github.io/planout/ does it.